# How do game clients handle actions that occurred in the past?

Tags: networking, client-server

Imagine you’re playing an online game with consistent latency. Your local clock is synced closely with the server.

Your character is moving along a straight line, you’re receiving information about the actions of the things around you, life is good.

You experience a latency spike and receive no data for 2 seconds. The local clock and simulation keeps chugging along, and then suddenly you receive a flood of actions that took place in the past.

If the code assumes that time is monotonic and going back in time isn’t possible, how can you resolve this divergence or prevent the local simulation from getting too far ahead?

Answer (score 2):

For a short period of time you can extrapolate/predict movement, and then interpolate when the connection is working again.

However, it makes less sense to do that as the period with no data becomes longer, since the state the player sees is bound to differ more and more from the truth. How long you can afford to rely on this approach depends on the game (a game that requires quick user reactions can't afford as much latency as - say - a turn based game).

At some point the best idea is to put at indicator on screen if it is not getting data for for a while (e.g. half a second). That way the player is aware that there is some issue with the connection - if things moving weird or stopping moving was not enough clue.

When the connection is working again, the client can simulate the actions it got and warp everything to the result. Yes, it would be jarring, but so is the period with no data.

Furthermore, if the server is not getting data from the client for several seconds (e.g. five seconds), you can have the server consider it a disconnection and stop sending data.

Then when the connection is working the client, the client can ask for the current state. This mechanism should take care of situations where simulating all the actions would be take longer than just requesting a full state update.

*Engineer the means to interrupt the connection to test the solution works correctly. And take advantage of said testing to tweak the time periods to something sensible for your game. It might very well be that after two seconds you should consider it a diconnection.*